# Cleaning rank-choice survey data in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning, survey

I have survey data I'm working on in R that includes questions where respondents were given a list of options and asked to rank their top five. The data looks like this:

```
head(data)
   responseid     ChoiceA     ChoiceB     ChoiceC     ChoiceD     ChoiceE     ChoiceF
1        001            5            2           1         NA           4           3    
2        002           NA            4           3          5           2           1            
3        003            3            1          NA          2           4           5             
4        004           NA            5           2          1           3           4
```

I'd like to reshape it so that it looks like this:

```
head(data_new)
   responseid     first     second     third     fourth     fifth
1        001          C          B         F          E         A      
2        002          F          E         C          B         D                                  
3        003          B          D         A          E         F                               
4        004          D          C         E          F         B
```

What would be an efficient way to do this, preferably in tidyverse? I feel like the answer is going to involve changing the values in a new column based on the names of other columns, which I can't figure out how to do.

I'm also pulling this data out of SurveyGizmo, so if anyone has suggestions for a way to set it up so that the data exports to a csv the way I want it in the first place, I would appreciate that as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gist is that you want to pivot longer, clean it up a bit and then pivot wider using the ranks as the column names instead of the choices. This is a similar method to akrun, though I think given the limit of five choices hardcoding the ordinal column names is less complex.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- read_table2(
"responseid     ChoiceA     ChoiceB     ChoiceC     ChoiceD     ChoiceE     ChoiceF
001            5            2           1         NA           4           3
002           NA            4           3          5           2           1
003            3            1          NA          2           4           5
004           NA            5           2          1           3           4"
)
tbl %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -responseid,
    names_to = "choice",
    values_to = "rank",
    values_drop_na = TRUE
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    choice = str_remove(choice, "Choice"),
    rank = c("first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth")[as.integer(rank)]
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = rank, values_from = choice) %>%
  select(responseid, first, second, third, fourth, fifth)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   responseid first second third fourth fifth
#>   <chr>      <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 001        C     B      F     E      A    
#> 2 002        F     E      C     B      D    
#> 3 003        B     D      A     E      F    
#> 4 004        D     C      E     F      B
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I got this to work, thank you! Any suggestions for replicating this over other questions? This works great for a single survey question, but I have a whole survey of these rank-choice questions, and this solution seems a little complicated to write into a function.

Comment: It depends on how the other questions differ... in number of options to choose from? no change needed. in number of choices selected? you'll need to make some kind of "n_choice" parameter. Or do you mean how can you apply this to many questions?

Answer (score 5):

We can reshape into 'long' format and then pivot it to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(english)
df1 %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -responseid, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
   separate(name, into = c("name1", "name2"), "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])") %>%     
   mutate(value = as.character(ordinal(value))) %>%  
   pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = name2)
```

Answer (score 1):

For interest, a one-liner in base R that produces the correct ordering:

```
gsub("Choice", "", t(apply(data_new, 1, function(x) names(data_new)[-1][order(x[-1])]))[,1:5])
#>   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> 1 "C"  "B"  "F"  "E"  "A" 
#> 2 "F"  "E"  "C"  "B"  "D" 
#> 3 "B"  "D"  "A"  "E"  "F" 
#> 4 "D"  "C"  "E"  "F"  "B"
```